How to return a complicated struct out of Pandas UDF in PySpark?
I struggle with writing a Pandas UDF that would return a complicated struct object. I have a function with the following signature:
def recipe_generator(
    shop_type_column: pd.Series,
    image_variant_id_column: pd.DataFrame,
    product_id_column: pd.Series,
) -> pd.DataFrame:

where the return type of the struct is somewhat as follows:
return_type = T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("url", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField(
                "devicePixelRatios",
                T.StructType(
                    [
                        T.StructField("original", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("1.5", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("2.0", T.StringType()),
                    ]
                ),
            ),
            T.StructField(
                "formats",
                T.StructType(
                    [
                        T.StructField("thumb-75", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("medium-200", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("medium-360", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("large-720", T.StringType()),
                        T.StructField("original", T.StringType()),
                    ]
                ),
            ),
            T.StructField("variants", T.ArrayType(T.StructType([T.StructField("id", T.StringType())]))),
        ]
    )

However, I cannot achieve it - I am tinkering things here and there but to no avail. I was able to implement the solution via pure udf, the non-pandas version, but here - no success.
For the record, that is the version of udf that worked:
F.udf(
    lambda shop_type, image_variants, product_id: LinkCreator().prepare_image_url_recipe(
        shop_type, image_variants, product_id
    ),
    returnType=return_type,
)

Please bear in mind, that the image_variant_id_column is of array type, which, I believe, complicates the situation even more. Is there any error in the way I approach it? What should I correct to make it pass? Maybe there is some trick to enable return of such a complicated struct?

can you include the code for the udf that you've successfully implemented?

@DerekO done. I included the necessary parts.
